# Find the all cases that satisfy an equality

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find which cases the following equality is satisfied.

```
Reduce[
  (x^(1 - α)/Gamma[β + 1])*D[f[x, t], x] == (x + 1/Gamma[α])^(1 - α)*D[f[x, t], x], 
  {x, t, α, β}
]
```

where [Gamma](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html) is the [gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) , `f[x, t]` is any differentiable function, and all variables are reals.

If the conditions are not adequate, we can suppose that `0 < α, β <= 1`.

Comment: The question is not clear as it stands. Is `f` some function that is known ahead of time, and if yes, what is it? Or is `f` itself an unknown? Btw, your equation is equivalent to `A*B==0` where `A = x^(1-\[Alpha])/Gamma[\[Beta]+1] -(x+1/Gamma[\[Beta]])^(1-\[Beta])` and `B = D[f[x,t],x]`.

Comment: Look at your equation. The function the derivative of `f ` appears on both sides of the equation  and cancels therefore.

Comment: If `f` is unknown then `DSolve[(x^(1-α)/Gamma[β+1])*D[f[x,t],x]==(x+1/Gamma[α])^(1-α)*D[f[x,t],x],f[x,t],{x,t}]` gives a very quick very simple solution for `f` and substituting that into the original equation verifies the result is `True`

Answer (score 1):

Get a graphical impression of solutions for x in dependence of a and b.

As @user293787 states, your equation is equivalent to A*B==0. Regard A.

```
eq = x^(1 - \[Alpha])/Gamma[\[Beta] + 1] D[f[x, t], 
      x] == (x + 1/Gamma[\[Beta]])^(1 - \[Beta]) D[f[x, t], 
      x] /. {\[Alpha] -> a, \[Beta] -> b};

A = eq /. D[f[x, t], x] -> 1

(*   x^(1 - a)/Gamma[1 + b] == (x + 1/Gamma[b])^(1 - b)   *)

cp1 = ContourPlot3D[
  x^(1 - a)/Gamma[1 + b] == (x + 1/Gamma[b])^(1 - b), {a, -3, 
   3}, {b, -5, 1}, {x, -1, 5}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, b, x}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{a, b, x}, x]]
```

[image]

Analytical solutions can be found only for some given parameters. Try more yourself.

```
lim1 = Limit[x^(1 - a)/Gamma[1 + b] - (x + 1/Gamma[b])^(1 - b), 
  b -> 1, Direction -> 1]

Reduce[0 == lim1 && a > 0, {x, a}, Reals] // LogicalExpand

(*   (a == 1 && x > 0) || (a == 1 && x < 0) || (x == 1 && 
   a > 0) || (C[1]/2 \[Element] Integers && x == -1 && 1 - C[1] == a &&
    C[1] <= 0)   *)

lim2 = Limit[x^(1 - a)/Gamma[1 + b] - (x + 1/Gamma[b])^(1 - b), 
  b -> 0, Direction -> -1]

Reduce[0 == lim2 && a > 0, {x, a}, Reals] // LogicalExpand

(*   (x == 1 && a > 0) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
   x == -1 && -C[1] == a && C[1] <= -1)   *)
```